# How do you reference a value of a class inside of a method in the same class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, methods

I have some Objective-C code:

```
@interface CustomInitializers:NSObject
{
     NSString *classStr;
     NSInteger classInt;
} 
+ (id) init;
+ (id) initWithString: (NSString *) stringToSet;
+ (id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) intToSet;
+ (id) initWithAll:(NSString *)stringToSet classInt:(NSInteger)intToSet;  
- (NSInteger) getClassInt;
- (NSString *) getClassStr;
@end
```

When I implement this class, I refer to the variables by prefixing them with an underscore (e.g. _classStr). However, this prompts an error when compiling:

```
[file name]:[line number]:[character]: Usage of undeclared identifer "_randSen"
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following instance variables:

```
{
     NSString *classStr;
     NSInteger classInt;
}
```

are both scoped ***instance*** variables for the class. When you create a property via:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *classStr;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSInteger classInt;
```

A getter and setter are generated to access an instance variable that is generated. The auto generated instance variables consist of the property name prepended by an underscore.

What you're doing is just creating the instance variable. So:

```
 NSString *classStr;
 NSInteger classInt;
```

is in fact your instance variables. If you wanted them to be prepended with an underscore (proper methodology), you should prepend them as such:

```
 NSString *_classStr;
 NSInteger _classInt;
```

In reality, if they're in your header, you should be using properties. Only private instance variables should be done as scoped instance variables and these would exist in the implementation file rather the header.

There's plenty of information out there explaining this in greater details: [link](https://www.quora.com/Objective-C-programming-language-What-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-variable-and-a-property)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to stop a property from generating a getter and setter?

Comment: No, the purpose of a property is to auto generate a getter/setter/and instance variable. It's pretty standard. If you want a private property, just put it in the implementation file. If you really do just want the instance variable (which is usually for a very very particular reason and is not typically recommended without a good reason), just do the above regarding moving your variables into your implementation file and pre pending an underscore to denote them as instance variables.

Comment: 99% of the time you should be using properties though

Comment: Will adding the value to the implementation file make it "import-global" [sic]? As in, if I do: #import "ThisCode.m", will that code have that variable available for anything to use?

Comment: There IS a way to stop a property from synthesising its own getter/setter, and it is very simple. Just write your getter and setter and the property will no longer roll its own.

Comment: Jef technically the getters and setters don't go away, at this point you create them yourselves and depending on how you approach this, you may have to define an instance variable yourself via @synthesize. Either way, these are all things that should be researched more by SahibPrime to understand what he/she wants and what he/she should do. You are correct though in saying when you create them, they are not auto generated though.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is declared within a method it means it only exists within that scope thus the simple answer is you can't access it. A solution would be to make the variable an instance property so that you can access it from any method within your class.